# How to disable WebRTC in Google Chrome without using an extension or plugin?

Tags: google-chrome, webrtc

I want to disable WebRTC in Google Chrome in the browser settings, like you can in Firefox, or to block it with another program. I don't want to use an extension that can be uninstalled or disabled. Ideally, I would also like to be able to deploy this across a couple dozen workstations, hence my desire to use something that is more "permanent" than an extension. Even if there is no easily accessible "setting" for it, I am wondering if there could be a way to edit a CSS file or something. As far as I know, there is no Chrome equivalent to Firefox's `about:config` page, but maybe there is something similar I have yet to discover?

Sorry for the nebulous sounding question, I am just kind of flailing in the dark here, I have very limited experience with any sort of programming and focus primarily in hardware diagnostics and Windows systems/network admin, but I am interested in learning at least some basics for diagnostic purposes.

Answer (score 2):

From what I have tried, you can do the following:

1. Locate your Chrome user preference file.

   - Windows Vista / 7 / 8 / 8.1:

     ```
     C:\Users\(your_username)\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Preferences
     ```
   - Mac OSX:

     ```
     ~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Preferences
     ```
   - GNU/Linux:

     ```
     ~/.config/google-chrome/Default/Preferences
     ```
2. Exit Chrome and save a backup copy of the file `Preferences` somewhere else. Make sure Chrome is not running in background.
3. Open the `Preferences` file in a text editor (e.g. Notepad++, Sublime Text, gedit).
4. Add this line to the bottom of the file, paying attention to the format. (Just follow the format of the other lines, adding a comma if necessary.)

   ```
   "webrtc":{"multiple_routes_enabled":false}
   ```

If you have doubts, here is a fragment of the last lines of my `Preferences` file before the modification:

```
"spellcheck":{"dictionaries":["en-US"],"dictionary":""},
"translate_ignored_count_for_language":{"es":44,"und":2},
"zerosuggest":{"cachedresults":""}}
```

And here is the file after the modification:

```
"spellcheck":{"dictionaries":["en-US"],"dictionary":""},
"translate_ignored_count_for_language":{"es":44,"und":2},
"webrtc":{"multiple_routes_enabled":false},
"zerosuggest":{"cachedresults":""}}
```

And then you're done. You can verify if this is working by using [this website](http://www.vpninsights.com/webrtc-leak-test).

Before disabling WebRTC:
[image: enabled_webrtc_in_chrome]

After disabling WebRTC:
[image: disabled_webrtc_in_chrome]

> Note: If you accidentally made a modification that causes an error and Chrome won't start anymore, you can replace the `Preferences` file with the backup copy you saved earlier.

At this moment there is no ideal solution to disable WebRTC on desktop with a simple click or without using an extension, in the mobile version of Google Chrome you can go to `chrome://flags/` And search for `webrtc` there will be some options that you can disable there.

Another solution will be to use [Slimjet](https://www.slimjet.com/en/faq.php), this is a Chromium-based project which uses the same Blink engine as Google Chrome but offers an [easy option to disable WebRTC](https://www.slimjet.com/en/how-to-disable-webrtc-in-chrome.php).

Hope it helps.

Comment: chrome://flags/#disable-webrtc - no such thing in latest chrome

Comment: That is just available in mobile version of Google Chrome.

Comment: Yes, sorry - I've omitted that info ;)

Comment: The `"webrtc":{"multiple_routes_enabled":false}` does not seem to work anymore (Chrome Update?). Does anyone know any solution?